# $\{u \in C^2([0, 1]) : \|u\|_{C^2} \le 1\}$ compact in $C^1([0, 1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider $B := \{u \in C^2([0, 1]) : \|u\|_{C^2} \le 1\}$ as a subset of $C^1([0, 1])$. Is $B$ compact in $C^1([0, 1])$?

Whoops, I guess I should clarified that $\|u\|_{C^k} := \sum_0^k \sup_{x \in I} |u^{(i)}(x)|$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Users tend to be more receptive if you also add some context to the question - some motivation for it, or perhaps any ideas you've tried already

Comment: Is this set closed?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not even closed. Using the interval $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$, one can see that the sequence
$$f_n(x) = |x|^{2+1/n}\operatorname{sign} x$$
converges in $C^1$ norm to $f(x)=|x|^2\operatorname{sign} x$ which is not in $C^2$.

Indeed, $f_n'(x) = (2+1/n)|x|^{1+1/n}$ converges uniformly to $f'(x) = 2|x|$.

The second derivatives  $f_n''(x)=(2+1/n)(1+1/n)|x|^{1/n}\operatorname{sign}x$ are uniformly bounded; they just need to be scaled down a bit.